# Deriving solution of a second order ode from a closely related one with a different scalar coefficient for the term in X(x)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, power-series, perturbation-theory, parabolic-pde

I solved the wrong differential equation!

I was looking at a parabolic pde in the style of a heat equations which upon separation of variables  I wrote as
\begin{equation}
a x^2\left(\frac{d^2 X}{d x^2} + \frac{d X}{d x}\right)  - b \left( \frac{d X}{d x}  +X\right) -k =0 \quad\quad\quad{(*)}
\end{equation}
but this would be wrong as I should have written
\begin{equation}
a x^2\left(\frac{d^2 X}{d x^2} + \frac{d X}{d x}\right)  - b \left( \frac{d X}{d x}  +X\right) -\tilde{k} X =0.\quad\quad\quad(\dagger)
\end{equation}
The solution of ($*$) was attractive so I share it below.  Introduce $R = \frac{dX}{dx} + X$  so that
\begin{equation}
ax^2 \frac{dR}{dx} -b R -k = 0
\end{equation}
whose solution  for $R$ is
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{dR}{k +b R}   =  \frac{\log( k  + b R)}{r} = \int \frac{ dx}{a x^2}  = - \frac{1}{a x} + c_1
\end{equation}
with $\phi_1 = e^{c_1}$ representing the constant of integration to give
\begin{equation}
R= (  \frac{d X}{d x}  + X) =\frac{\phi_1}{b}  \exp\left(- \frac{b}{ax}\right) -\frac{k}{b}.
\end{equation}
We can employ an integration factor of $e^{x}$ gives
\begin{eqnarray}
 \int d ( e^{x} X) &=& \int \left(\frac{\phi_1}{b}  e^{x}   \exp\left(- \frac{b}{a x}\right) -\frac{k}{b} e^{x} \right) dx  + c_0 \\
X(x) &=&  e^{-x} \int \left ( \frac{\phi_1}{b}  e^{x} \exp\left(- \frac{b}{a x}\right) -\frac{k}{b} e^{x} \right)\; dx  + c_0 \\
       &=&  \frac{\phi_1}{b}  e^{-x} \int  \exp\left(x - \frac{b}{a x}\right)\; dx\;  -  \frac{k}{b}  + c_0
\end{eqnarray}
The  integral has the form  $\int \exp(x -a/x) \;dx$.   Expressing $\exp(x) $ as a series, taking its product with $\exp(-a/(bx))$ and integrating termwise gives
\begin{equation}
\int \exp \left(x -\frac{a}{bx}\right) \; dx  \quad =  \quad
\frac{a}{b}\, \text{Ei}\left(-\frac{a}{bx}\right) \underset{n=0}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}\frac{(-a/b)^n}{n! (n+1)!}\;+\;x\,\exp\left(-\frac{a}{bx}\right) \underset{m=0}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}\left(\frac{\underset{n=0}{\overset{m}{\sum }}(-a/b)^{m-n} \, x^n\, n!}{m! (m+1)!}\right)
\end{equation}
where $\text{Ei}(\cdot)$ is the Exponential Integral function
\begin{equation}
\text{Ei}(z) \equiv  -\int_{-z}^{\infty } \frac{e^{-u}}{u} \; du \equiv  \int_{-\infty}^{z } \frac{e^{u}}{u} \; du.
\end{equation}
so all we need to solve the **'wrong'** ode (*) is in place.

My question is with a solution to the **'wrong'** ode (*) is it possible to obtain a solution to the **'right'** one ($\dagger$)?   Is this a use case for perturbation, or is there another approach I can take to solve ($\dagger$)?